# Error: The given key does not identify an element in this collection value

Tags: terraform

In terraform local block I have created the array of objects named yamlfs.

Value of yamlfs

```
yamlfs = [
    {
      "value" = {
        "annotations" = {}
        "labels" = {
          "name"  = "practiceeditors"
          "owner" = "xd-cloud-devops_at_abc.com"
        }
        "managed-identity-name" = "xac-internal-us-practiceeditors-identity"
        "namespace"             = "practiceeditors"
      }
    },

    {
      "value" = {
        "annotations" = {}
        "labels" = {
          "name"  = "practice1editors"
          "owner" = "xd-cloud-devops_at_abc.com"
        }
        "namespace"             = "practice1editors"
      }
    },
  ]
```

In the above data I need to fetch the namespace based on the passed managed-identity-name.

Here is the code for the logic

```
matching_files = [for file in local.yamlfs : file.value["namespace"] if contains(keys(file.value), "managed-identity-name") && file.value["managed-identity-name"] == local.managed-identity-name ]
```

Full code.

```
locals {
  managed-identity-name = "xac-internal-us-practiceeditors-identity"

  yamlfs = [
    {
      "value" = {
        "annotations" = {}
        "labels" = {
          "name"  = "practiceeditors"
          "owner" = "xd-cloud-devops_at_abc.com"
        }
        "managed-identity-name" = "xac-internal-us-practiceeditors-identity"
        "namespace"             = "practiceeditors"
      }
    },

    {
      "value" = {
        "annotations" = {}
        "labels" = {
          "name"  = "practice1editors"
          "owner" = "xd-cloud-devops_at_abc.com"
        }
        "namespace"             = "practice1editors"
      }
    },
  ]


  matching_files = [for file in local.yamlfs : file.value["namespace"] if contains(keys(file.value), "managed-identity-name") && file.value["managed-identity-name"] == local.managed-identity-name ]
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on local.tf line 112, in locals:
│  112:   matching_files = [for file in local.yamlfs : file.value["namespace"] if contains(keys(file.value), "managed-identity-name") && file.value["managed-identity-name"] == local.managed-identity-name ]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ file.value is object with 3 attributes
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

I have the following questions:

1. How can I fetch the namespace value based on the managed-identity?
2. Why is my logic failing even before accessing the data? I am checking the key using the "contains" keyword.

Please help me resolve this error and also answer my second question. I am new to the Terraform stack and would appreciate your assistance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Terraform's HCL2 DSL does not evaluate lazily in this situation and therefore you cannot "short circuit" the logical in the condition like you would expect with most other languages. The workaround here likely involves the use of one or more of the following functions: `coalesce` (analogous to null coalescing operators), `can`, and/or `anytrue`.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by accessing absent property from structure, examples below uses [terraform console](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/console):

```
> {"a": 123}["b"]
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on <console-input> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

You can fix this using [lookup](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/lookup) function:

```
> lookup({"a": 123}, "a", 0)
123
> lookup({"a": 123}, "b", 0)
0
```